# How to open dialogbox to browse files in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, dialog

When I executed :
`OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();`

I am getting the below **error** :

> The base class or interface 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in
>   assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog' could not be resolved c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll

P.S.: I have added reference to assembly `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in reference of solution.

Comment: OpenFileDialog is a Windows specific method.  You cannot use arbitrary Windows DLLs in a Xamarin project.

Comment: Then, how to do open a File system dialog in xamarin app?

Comment: Hi, I am having same issues did you managed to find a solution for your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

There's no simple way to open a file browser in Xamarin.Forms as environments such as iOS don't allow browsing the file system.

The link below shows a recipe of how to achieve something like what you want on Android.

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/browse_files/